# Log File Downloads from SSRS Native Server

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have a 2016 SQL Reporting Services server setup in native mode where I store the usual .dtsx reports on there alongside some legacy excel reports that are manually uploaded. I can track when each report is run in a variety of ways but I'm unsure how to track the excel file downloads which I will use a rough metric of usage. I've tried the following:

- Execution Log view in Database --Only records report execution.
- SSRS Log files with HTTP Enabled -- Default Logs, and then with [HTTP logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-http-log?view=sql-server-2017) enabled, both which do not record the act of downloading the excel file.
- As per comment below, IIS is separated from SSRS2016 <s>Enable [logging on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis) (server and website level) - No log file is created. I assume this is because IIS passes traffic directly to SSRS2016 which uses some internal library to host it site.</s>

How can I log each time a file is downloaded from my SSRS report server?

Comment: IIS is not involved anymore with SSRS 2016.  It was removed in 2008 I think.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the case as per this blog. Thanks for help narrow it down if nothing else: https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/07/ssrs-does-not-require-iis/